# Anybody's helps me how to connect my hosting MySQL database on my local computer

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, web-hosting

I want my hosting server MySQL database connect on my local pc because i can input data from my local pc please help me how how to connect this

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :) But keep in mind that SO is a community that helps, and no one will do all the work for you. Please show us some code you messed up with and we'll be glad to help improve it...

Answer (score 0):

Install something like XAMPP which include Apache,MySQL,PHP. Then start Apache and MySQL servers and you can get connection to your MySQL using

```
localhost/phpmyadmin
```

put that into ulr on your browser(Chrome, Firefox,etc..)